# Shellscript copying a file line by line to a new file and adding an extra line every 50 lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i counter=1
declare -i var=1
while read line
do
        echo $line >> newUpdateScript.sql
        counter=$(( $counter + $var ))
        echo $counter
        if [ $counter -eq 50  ]; then
                echo "commit;" >> newUpdateScript.sql
                counter=$var
        fi
done < UpdateScript.sql
echo "commit;" >> newUpdateScript.sql
```

This script is to read a file "UpdateScript.sql" line by line and write to a new file, after writing every 50 line, the program appends a "commit;" and then continues copying over the rest and appends a final "commit;" towards the end as well;

however instead of appending the desired "commit;" after every 50 lines, it does it after the 50 lines and then right after the next 4 lines.

Sample output:

```
Line 49
commit;
Line 51
Line 52
Line 53
commit;
Line 54
```

Please can someone help me debug this ?

Comment: If your goal is just to add `commit;` after every 50 lines, then try this : `sed '50~50{s/.*/&\ncommit;/;}' your.sql`. Let's make it simple.

Comment: That script doesn't have that behaviour here. It also doesn't quite work correctly because the math is slightly off but that's a different issue.

Comment: @sat You should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: your problem cannot be reproduced here.

Comment: I **guess** the result come from your multiple test.  you **append** `commit` every 50 lines **and** when finish processing the input file, we call it "last commit". so the `commit;` after line 53. was actually the "last commit". when you do next test, without making the new.sql empty, you keep seeing the "wrong" commit msgs. empty your new.sql file, every time you do test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add `commit;` after every 50 lines, use this

```
sed '50~50{s/.*/&\ncommit;/;}' yourfile.sql
```

To affect the changes in the file,

```
sed -i.bak '50~50{s/.*/&\ncommit;/;}' yourfile.sql
```

Here,

- `-i.bak` - will take a backup of yourfile.sql with the given extension (i.e `.bak` ).